# Set focus on ComboBox (ActiveX Control) after code execution

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel file with a combobox (name = "Combobox1"). After running a script (basically pasting the selected value in "the next row" of a column) I want the focus to be reset on the combobox at the end of the script, so doing allowing me to type the next entry in the Combobox without having to click on the ComboBox text field first.

This does the job in Excel 2013 but I would like to have it working in 2007 as well:

```
Combobox1.Activate
```

Anyone any idea?

Or:
I can replace the combobox with an in-cell dropdown list (data validation) and the same data validation as the one I have in the combobox at the moment, but then I have another issue:
For a ComboBox you can choose to have the dropdown list active, but for an in-cell data validation that is not the case, at least not if you want to be able to type in the cell after the list is shown with ALT+UP or

```
Application.SendKeys "%{UP}"
```

Any idea here?

Comment: I have no way to test this using Excel 2007. But the `.Activate` method should work the same way regardless of version. How did you say it is not working?

Comment: Sorry I have form controls on the mind. SetFocus would work on a form control. I tested the .activate on 2010 and it worked correctly. I will test on a 2007 version Monday, but i would see no reason why it would not work. Are you experiencing an error or just concerned that there might be a difference between the '07 and '13?

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I created a macro for someone else, it worked perfectly on my computer (Office 2013) but not on this person's computer (2007) nor on someone else's (also 2007) but I have not verified this myself. No error message. The focus just doesn't return / go to the combobox, user has to click manually on the textbox to activate it.

Comment: @MM7 I tested with excel 2007 and it worked without problem. Do you have no service pack installed? And could you post code before and after the comboBox activate?

Comment: I also tested a simple .Activate procedure in 2007 to activate a Combobox located on the worksheet. The Combobox activated as expected. You may want to ensure that the end user has not disable macros.

Answer (score 0):

If this combobox is on a worksheet and not a userform, then "Combobox1.select" should return the focus to the combobox.